# Extruding face without leaving gap / hole behind

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, extrude

Is it possible to extrude a face without leaving a hole / gap behind?  See animation below.  I would like it to remain a closed / filled face.

[image: gif 1]

I'm trying to avoid having to go back and fill in all the holes I may need to create after extruding.

Comment: Hi :). Just keep in mind this would lead to non-manifold geometry. Unless that's what you want.

Comment: No, I don't want that is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: inset to value one with 'i', then extrude. I'm surprised though that it does what you show

Comment: @Yvain doing a inset with a value of 1 just makes the face smaller, and the hole is still there just smaller.

Comment: Did you try it ? Inset at zero maybe to keep the same size and then extrude, you should keep your bottom... don't forget to recalculate normals after

Comment: @Yvain yes I tried 1 and 0 as inset values, it still creates a hole when extruding.  Didn't recalculate normals since the hole is still there.

Comment: that's the way it works, if you want to avoid the hole you need to give thickness to your faces underneath, or you can still fill the hole but this is bad topology

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the way extrusion works when there's another face next to the one you extrude:

[image]

You can still fill the face but it's not a good topology to have more that 2 faces connected to an edge:

[image]

To have a good topology give thickness to your bottom faces:

[image]